# Rendering issues and cannot resolve R in Android Studio 2.0, why it occurs and how to solve these?

Tags: android, junit, rendering

I tried to comment the junit part of the code, in gradle as well as in java. And it is working properly. But is this the only way to solve this? And why commenting the junit it is working? Why does the issue occur? Any better alternative?